# Trying to build Apache ODE source code with Buildr

Tags: apache, build, buildr, apache-ode

i am trying to build APACHE ODE source code with Buildr using Ruby. I installed ruby and installed Buildr with it, but when i run the command rake package on the root of APACHE ODE source code it gives me this error

C:\workspace2\APACHE_ODE_1.X>rake package --trace
(in C:/workspace2/APACHE_ODE_1.X)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Gem::Requirement::OP_RE

The gems i have installed

C:\workspace2\APACHE_ODE_1.X>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

Antwrap (0.7.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
builder (2.1.2)
buildr (1.3.5)
highline (1.5.1)
hoe (2.3.3)
net-sftp (2.0.2)
net-ssh (2.0.15)
rake (0.8.7)
rjb (1.1.6)
rspec (1.2.8)
rubyforge (1.0.5)
rubygems-update (1.3.6)
rubyzip (0.9.1)
xml-simple (1.0.12)

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering from the same problem and so are others (see this [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BUILDR-384) bug ticket).

Upgrading to Buildr 1.4 should fix the problem.

**Edit**: I just tried upgrading to Buildr 1.4.

There wasn't a package anywhere so I got it straight from GitHub, here are my steps.

```
git clone http://github.com/apache/buildr.git
cd buildr
sudo gem build buildr.gemspec
sudo env JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME gem install buildr-1.4.0.gem
```

This fixed the problem described in the question. I was though unable to install Apache Ode because of a new problem, but if you don't run into that one then no reason for me to try to find out the cause for it yet :)